# A docker container does not free memory from a process that writes huge amounts of data into a file

Tags: docker, kubernetes

a docker container does not free memory from a process that writes huge amounts of data into a file (logger), so I'm interested why it`s possible and how to fix it in my case. I have used a lot of log package, all log package have the same issue

Comment: when I exec  "echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches", the memory will free